# Use of pseudo-random binary sequence (Gold, Kasami, etc.) in frequency hopped code-division multiple access (FH/CDMA)

Tags: digital-communications, spread-spectrum

I have a clear idea of how a PN-sequence is used in a Direct Sequence Code-Division Multiple Access(DS-CDMA) system with BPSK. In such a system, a different pn-sequence is assigned to each user and each transmitted bit is XORed with the binary pn-sequence.

Now my question is:

For each symbol time, how are this binary pn-sequences used in a FH/CDMA system to chose which hop frequency to use if there are more than two possible hop frequencies?

If I have 2 possible hop frequencies to use, the answer is trivial, because each bit of the pseudo-random sequence would tell which of the two hop frequencies must be used. But when having more than two frequencies... How is this selection done?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. A simple method is to take the current value of the register (not just its output) as the carrier frequency selector. For instance, a (6,1) LFSR with 63 states can select between 63 different channels.

Other methods are based on cubic and quadratic congruence codes. I don't know much about them myself, but look up the papers by Titlebaum et al.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer by @MBaz points out, one can use the *contents* of a $n$-bit maximal-length binary LFSR to select from $2^n-1$ different frequencies to hop to, thus creating a *frequency-hopping* sequence of period $2^n-1$. The difficulty is in creating *more* than one frequency-hopping sequence for use in a *multiple-access* scheme: the FH/CD**MA** scheme that the OP refers to.  A lot of useful information about this problem and its various solutions can be found in Chapter 8 "Reed-Solomon Codes and the Design of Sequences for Spread-Spectrum Multiple-Access Communications" of the book *Reed-Solomon Codes and Their Applications,* S. B. Wicker and V. K Bhargava, Eds., IEEE Press, 1994. The works of Titlebaum *et al.* mentioned by MBaz are related to the Reed-Solomon constructions described in the book chapter.

The chapter mentioned above also points out that the Gold sequences and the Kasami sequences can be viewed as *mappings* of codewords of low-rate Reed-Solomon codes to binary sequences (essentially, throw away all the bits except one from each codeword symbol of the Reed-Solomon codeword, and what is left is a Gold sequence or a Kasami sequence). As a concrete example, consider that the output of a $n$-bit maximal-length LFSR is a maximal-length sequence (a special case of a Gold sequence) while the entire contents of the LFSR are the frequency-hopping sequence suggested by MBaz.